# How can I create a loop to get two latest dates in a range of cells in a row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that works to loop through a range to find out if the date is less than the current date and if so clear the cell as well as the two cells in front of it.  But I am having problems getting a code to then loop through the same range and find the two most recent dates and clear the contents like the first loop of all the others but the latest two dates.  Since I am just a novice at coding I have not been able to get it to work even with help from some sites on line.

Here is the latest thing I have tried to loop back through and find two latest dates.

```
For Each cell In Range("Q2:Q1000")
        If cell.Value < cell.Offset(0, 3).Value Or cell.Offset(0, 
        6).Value Or 
        cell.Offset(0, 9).Value Or cell.Offset(0, 12).Value Or 
         cell.Offset(0,15).Value Then
       cell.ClearContents
       End If

       If cell = "" Then
       cell.Offset(, -1) = ""
       cell.Offset(, -2) = ""
       End If




Here is the code to find out if contents is more than 2 years old.



For Each cell In Range("Q2:Q1000")
        If cell.Value < (currentDate - 730) Then
        cell.ClearContents

       End If


       If cell = "" Then
       cell.Offset(, -1) = ""
       cell.Offset(, -2) = ""
       End If

Next
```

I think I am missing something simple but cannot find it.

Comment: Have you tried the `Max` function to find the largest (soonest) date?

Comment: You have to write `If cell.Value < cell.Offset(0, 3).Value Or cell.Value < cell.Offset(0,       6).Value` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method to clear all cells with dates older than the two most recent dates.  This assumes your values in `Range("Q2:Q1000")` are properly formatted `Date` cells:

```
Dim cel as Range

For CurRow = 2 to 1000
    'Find the 2nd most recent date:
    BeforeDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(Range("Q" & CurRow & ",T" & CurRow & ",W" & CurRow & ",Z" & CurRow & ",AC" & CurRow & ",AF" & CurRow),2)

    For Each cel In Range("Q" & CurRow & ",T" & CurRow & ",W" & CurRow & ",Z" & CurRow & ",AC" & CurRow & ",AF" & CurRow)
        If cel.Value < BeforeDate Then
            cel.ClearContents
            cel.Offset(, -1) = ""
            cel.Offset(, -2) = ""
        End If
    Next cel
Next CurRow
```

Comment: That looks like a possible solution except  it looks like I may have not given enough info on the issue.  The BeforeDate looks great but the range I am comparing is in the range ("Q2,T2,W2,Z2,AC2,AF2"). Then same comparison same columns one row down up to 1000 rows.  What would that loop look like running this code starting with range Q2,T2,W2,Z2,AC2,AF2 then same columns in row 3 and so on?

Comment: The solution worked when I use the following code but only for that row need to loop through sheet to row 1000.                                                                                                                 Dim cel As Range
    'Find the 2nd most recent date:
BeforeDate= Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(Range("Q2,T2,W2,Z2,AC2,AF2"), 2)
For Each cel In Range("Q2,T2,W2,Z2,AC2,AF2")
    If cel.Value < BeforeDate Then
        cel.ClearContents
    cel.Offset(, -1) = ""
     cel.Offset(, -2) = ""
   End If
Next cel

Comment: @Mark Updated with row loop.